# add caption text using javascript and php

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add some caption text to a div position, named

```
<div id="slidecaption"></div>
```

So in my js here is the code:

```
slides                  :   [   <?php 
    //query
    query_posts(array('post_type'=>'slider',
                      'posts_per_page'=>'20'
                      ));

    //loop
    if(have_posts()) : 
        while (have_posts()) : the_post();
            //feature image
            $large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full');
            $title = get_the_title();

            //echo slides
            echo "{image : '".$large_image_url[0]."', title : '<h1>This is a header</h1>', url : ''},";

        endwhile; 
    endif; 
?>]
```

What i need is to display the title inside the div above..
How can i do that?
Thanks!

Comment: and whr is this code ? in js file or in php file ?

Comment: Sorry, i'll have to delete this question :)
solved it, the issue was me not seeing pretty well :D

Comment: `$('#slidecaption').text('<?php echo $title ?>')`

Comment: @AlbM good to see you solve it on your own :)